# Python & GTK3: How to create a Liststore

Tags: python, pygobject, gtk3

In PyGtk I always used this to create a ListStore with an Image (using it with an IconView for displaying files):

```
store = gtk.ListStore(str, gtk.gdk.Pixbuf, bool)
```

But I can't figure out how to do this with Python 3 and PyGObject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf
store = Gtk.ListStore(str, GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf, bool)
```